# Possibility to auto-assign persons that drag and drop Kanban cards

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

Our team uses the Kanban board in Azure DevOps.

We were wondering: if we have an unassigned card and a team member moves it across the board is there a way to assign that person **automatically** to the card? (or change an already assigned person).

Would highly appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Rule in the Process configuration that has the Action to set the `Current User` value to the `AssignedTo` field when a work item changes to a specified state (i.e. the Condition).

[Example rule in the ADO Boards Process configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzFeZ.jpg)

The example Rule in the linked snip results in a User Story being assigned to the user who drags the ticket to the Active state. Obviously there are different conditions you could come up with to best achieve your goals.

Note that rules are created per work item (e.g. User Story, Task, Bug etc) so you would need to create a rule per work item where you wanted this behaviour.

If you need more information on creating rules then [this ADO page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) is a good resource. You will need the ability to edit the ADO Boards Process that your project is using.